# php Is there a way to use switch statement for 3 or more cases

Tags: php, switch-statement

Is there a way to use switch statement for 3 or more cases?

```
<div>
<?php switch($variable): 
case 1: ?>
<div>
Newspage
</div>
<?php break;?>
<?php case 2: ?>
</div>
Forum
<div>
<?php break;?>
<?php case 3: ?>
</div>
Blogs
<div>
<?php break;?>
<?php endswitch;?>
</div>
```

because I get expected statement error message.

Comment: Works fine for me. Something must be wrong in the rest of your code.

Comment: You can use switch for as many cases as you want. Show us the full script, and the actual error message.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting? What line of code is it referencing?

Comment: your code is working fine. it also works for 4th case.

Comment: It was problem in my phpstorm validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`because I get expected statement error message.`

I'm guessing you get **unexpected** switch error messages?

In that case you have not completed an earlier statement (or have syntax-errors). We need more code in any case.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($variable):  should be

switch($variable){
```

It opens and closes with a bracket. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp for correct syntax.